# The necessity of non-negativity for the inequality $\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z^n}f(k+y) \ge \int_{\Bbb R^n} f(x)\,dx$

Tags: measure-theory

I'm working through a proof for Minkowski's convex body theorem and there is a short technical lemma relating the sum of an integrable function $f$ over a translate of the integer lattice and its integral over $\Bbb R^n$. I have not been able to discern why non-negativity was assumed. For completeness, I present the given proof below.

> **Lemma** Let $f(x)$ be a non-negative integrable function on $\Bbb R^n$ with $$\int_{\Bbb R^n} f(x)\,dx < \infty.$$ Then there exists a $y\in\Bbb R^n$ such that $$\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z^n} f(k+y) \ge \int_{\Bbb R^n} f(x)\,dx.$$

**Proof:** If $\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z^n} f(k+y) = \infty$ for any $y\in\Bbb R^n$, then the result is trivial. Otherwise, assume that for all $y$ it is finite. Then breaking up the integral over $\Bbb R^n$ into a sum of integrals over unit cubes:

$$\int_{\Bbb R^n} f(x)\,dx = \sum_{k\in\Bbb Z^n}\int_{[0,1)^n} f(k+x)\,dx.$$

Since the sum $\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z^n}f(k+y)$ is assumed to be finite for all $y$, integrating said sum over $[0,1)^n$ is finite and so we can interchange the sum and limit to get

$$\int_{\Bbb R^n} f(x)\,dx = \int_{[0,1)^n}\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z^n} f(k+x)\,dx.$$

Define the function $g(x) = \sum_{k\in\Bbb Z^n} f(k+x)$, then

$$\int_{[0,1)^n} g(x)\,dx = \frac{1}{m([0,1)^n)} \int_{[0,1)^n} g(x)\,dx,$$

where $m([0,1)^n)$ denotes the measure of $[0,1)^n$. The latter can easily be recognized as the average value of $g$ over $[0,1)^n$. Thus there is some $y\in [0,1)^n$ such that $g(y) \ge \int_{[0,1)^n} g(x)\,dx$, i.e.

$$\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z^n}f(k+y) \ge \int_{\Bbb R^n} f(x)\,dx.$$

---

This is all well and good. I understand the logic, though there seem to be a couple of questionable points to me. Not that the logic is flawed, just that there are better/more general ways to present the argument.

1. I feel like the assumption of the finiteness of $\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z^n} f(x+y)$ for all $y$ is not quite necessary. Assuming that $f$ has finite integral over $\Bbb R^n$ should (to me) allow us to interchange the integral and sum directly by Tonelli's theorem.
2. I feel like we should be able to get away with not assuming non-negativity by assuming that $\int_{\Bbb R^n}|f(x)|\,dx < \infty$ and making use of Fubini-Tonelli (in place of Tonelli) to interchange the integral and sum. From there it seems to me that the analysis would follow exactly as in the proof above.

Is there a flaw in the logic in either of these two points?

Comment: What you have written is perfectly correct. It suffices to assume $\int |f| <\infty $. But if you assume $f $ to be nonnegative, you can save some thinking about whether the reasoning indeed remains true in the general case :)

Comment: The modified statement would be: There is $y $ for which the series converges absolutely and such that $\sum \dots \geq \int \dots $.

Comment: Thanks, @PhoemueX! I also consulted a colleague and it seems it's all good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $f$ is non-negative, then for every $y$ you have exactly one of two options: either $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}^n}f(y+k)$ is finite, or else it is infinite; but you cannot assert this when $f$ changes signs, for it may happen that the series diverges. For example, if $n=1$ you can take any $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and change it's values on the integers without affecting the integral. (I am assuming Lebesgue-integration), and so you can easily create a function for which the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\,dx$ is finite but $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(k)$ diverges - it is not finite, neither infinite - it just does not exist.

Comment: I agree with this and considered this. You can change $f$ so that for *some* $y$ the series diverges but this does not necessarily mean that it does for all $y$. For such $y$, $g$ will be ill defined, but that can be fixed by setting $g$ to zero at those points. It does not change any of the following analysis.

Comment: I think it does change the analysis. I don't see how you can "fix" $g$. The sum over the integers may not exist on an uncountable subset of points $x$, and then you are in trouble. In particular, you cannot change the order of integration and summation. In fact, can you  write down a rigourous proof for the case $n=1$, where you start with your favorite $f$ and I modify it so that $f(n)=(-1)^nn$ for every integer $n$?

Comment: I guess my point was that you can do it on any given point but it isn't obvious that it can diverge on an uncountable subset. I haven't a clue as to how to go about showing that might be possible though.